# Ruby Savon Gem Invalid HTTPI Adapter

Tags: ruby, savon, ocra

I am using savon ruby gem 2.4.0 on ruby 2.0.0 to call some wsdl web service and everything runs perfectly but if fails after compiling it as an .exe with ocra 1.3.1.

> Invalid HTTPI adapter: [:httpclient, :curb, :em_http, :excon,
>   :net_http, :net_http_persistent]

What configuration is missing on the savon client ruby file since for now i am just providing the wsdl url.

Comment: Any luck with this--I think I might be experiencing a similar issue!

Comment: please provide more context information.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution identified!**

1. Create `Gemfile`
2. Add `savon` to `Gemfile`
3. Add `require 'httpclient'` to service

When compiling your service, I do believe that you can link to the Gemfile as such:

`ocra service.rb --gem-files='rel_path_to_gemfile' --gem-full`

Hope this helps!

Also, just FYI, I do believe that this is simply a workaround for a bug that lies within ocra where it is not actually packaging all of the necessary libraries!

Comment: i have to try this soon.